# If I have two tables I want to use join operation and if I have left join then what is the use of right join?

Tags: sql-server

If I have two tables I want to use join operation and if I have left join then what is the use of right join?

I have two tables A and B

I will use like

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.Id=B.Id
```

If I want B table as outer

```
SELECT * FROM B LEFT OUTER JOIN A ON B.Id=A.Id
```

then what is the use of right outer join?

Answer (score 2):

Having both joins helps one write intuitive scripts that are easier to understand. It is similar to why most programming languages have a less than comparison operator as well as a greater than comparison operator. In theory, most (if not all) code could be rewritten to use only one of them, but that code would be more difficult to understand and maintain.

Comment: Note that some RDBMSs (e.g., SQLite) do not implement `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` at all.